# Variables from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, websocket, computer-vision

I implemented a python script using opencv where i can detect the fingers and their widths.
my question is how can i retrieve the values of widths and the coordinates that i computed from the python script and give to javascript in roder to place a ring in the exact place?!using websockets maybe?, or better to use json?!
thanks

this is a function of computing the widths of fingers:

```
def calc_width_right(laliste):
widths = []
right_fingers_names = ["Index", "Middle finger", "Ring Finger", "Pinky"]
all_width = [list(value) for key, value in itertools.groupby(laliste) if key == 255]
if (len(all_width) == 4):
    for i in range(0,len(all_width)):
        widths.append(len(all_width[i]))
    print_names = list(zip(right_fingers_names,widths))
    print(print_names)
    calc_width_right.width_Index = print_names[0]
    calc_width_right.width_Middle = print_names[1]
    calc_width_right.width_RingF = print_names[2]
    calc_width_right.width_Pinky = print_names[3]
```

Comment: This is not clear. We need context here. If you create a web application using python (flask, django), you don't need websockets to use these on javascript side. You could use ajax and communicate data using json or you could use templated views.

Comment: @CorentinLimier sorry, i use Opencv-python, so in the server side, my python script will detect fingers in the image and compute their widths.
the client side i want to implement a javascript code to get those widths.

Comment: Sure but what framework do you use to create this server ?

Comment: there is no framework! i only used pure python with the library of OpenCV!.